# MUI Grid container height increases as the height of Paper increases

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an MUI `Grid container` and one of the Grid items have a `Paper` in it. As the text inside the paper increases, the height of the Grid too increases. This is usual, but I want the height of all the components to be the same. And if the content inside the card exceeds the height, I want it to overflow with scroll property (only for the paper).

Here is my container element

`<Grid container p={3} alignItems={"center"} spacing={2} maxHeight={"100%"}>`

Here's my Ppaer element

```
 <Grid item md={8} textAlign={"center"} xs={12}>
                  <Box>
                    {blogTitle === "" ? (
                      <Typography variant="h3" color={"info.main"}>
                        Select a blog to preview
                      </Typography>
                    ) : (
                      <Paper
                        sx={{
                          height: "100%",
                          overflow: "auto",
                          paddingTop: 4,
                          paddingBottom: 4,
                        }}
                      >
                        <Typography variant="h5" mb={3}>
                          {blogTitle}
                        </Typography>
                        <img src={blogImage} width={500} alt={blogTitle} />
                        <Typography variant="body2" textAlign={"justify"} p={3}>
                          {blogDesc}
                        </Typography>
                      </Paper>
                    )}
                  </Box>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: You can try add `maxHeight="...px"` in the style of `Paper` component.

Comment: maxHeight would need a static value. So if the other components change size, a static value maxHeight wouldn't work. I suggest you useRef to determine the height of the container after load, apply it to a container wrapping the paper element, have the paper element height:100% and add an overflow:scroll to that container. A code snippet would help